# Save data in the context variable in Python's invoke library (pyinvoke)

Tags: python, pyinvoke

Using the [Invoke library for Python](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/), I want to run a setup task first which saves some values in the [context variable](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/0.13.0/api/context.html) that all of the following tasks then can read and use.

[The documentation is quite short on that topic](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/0.13.0/concepts/context.html), however, it states that

> A common problem task runners face is transmission or storage of
>   values which are “global” for the current session - values loaded from
>   configuration files (or other configuration vectors), CLI flags,
>   **values set by ‘setup’ tasks**, etc.
>
> (emphasis by me)

, so that should actually be possible.

However, when I write this,

```
from invoke import task

@task
def set_context(context):
    context.foo = 'bar'

@task
def read_context(context):
    print(context.foo)
```

and run the file from the command line via `invoke read_context set_context` , then I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/config.py", line 69, in __getattr__
    return self._get(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/config.py", line 113, in _get
    value = self.config[key]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/config.py", line 110, in __getitem__
    return self._get(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/config.py", line 113, in _get
    value = self.config[key]
KeyError: 'foo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/invoke", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(program.run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/program.py", line 270, in run
    self.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/program.py", line 381, in execute
    executor.execute(*self.tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/executor.py", line 113, in execute
    result = call.task(*args, **call.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/tasks.py", line 111, in __call__
    result = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/Deploy_Birmingham_URL_Service_on_Docker_host/deployment/tasks.py", line 14, in read_context
    print(context.foo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/invoke/config.py", line 81, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(err)
AttributeError: No attribute or config key found for 'foo'

Valid keys: ['run', 'tasks']

Valid real attributes: ['from_data', 'run']
```

What is the correct way in `invoke` to save something in the context variable and re-use it in other tasks? I am using Python 3.5.2 and invoke 0.13.0 if that's important.

---

Note to future users: 0.15 fixed this ([github bug link)](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/413)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ctx.update`.

```
from invoke import task

@task
def set_context(context):
    context.update({'foo': 'bar'})

@task
def read_context(context):
    print(context.foo) # => 'bar'
```